# Fallo en servicio Rest

Tags: c#, rest

Estoy intentando realizar una operación por put en asp.net mvc, pero me da un fallo en:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Este es el fallo: {"Error en el servidor remoto: (404) No se encontró."}

Aquí dejo el código a ver si alguien sabe el porque de este fallo

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = metodo.ContentType;
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonData = jsSerializer.Serialize(datosPUT);
byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = arrData.Length;

Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
dataStream.Close ();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); //Fallo
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Pero sin embargo en otra platarforma de prueba frente al mismo servidor si funciona, lo malo que no tengo acceso a ella

Comment: ¿qué tipo de operación estás haciendo exáctamente?, el error 404 puede ser porque el recurso no existe. Ejemplo: _¿puede ser algún procedimiento almacenado, quizás?_.

Comment: de una base de datos coje un url y envia un id y una id de una sesion

Comment: Borja Clavo, Es posible que alguno de los datos que intentas obtener no exista en donde estés haciendo la prueba. Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta con lo que acabas de mencionar en tu comentario _y si es posible_ descríbenos un poco mas el problema: _qué datos estás usando, etc._

Comment: intentaste invocar el servicio rest usando Postman(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) es una extension para Chrome que permite invocar servicio rest. Podrias definir que se PUT y definir un body que represente el json que quieres enviar, de esta forma validas si el servicio responde correctamente con el json, porque puede que si el json no concuerda con los pametros lo rechace y genere este error

Comment: Como comenta Mauricio este error es porque no encuentra un recurso,pero no un stored procedure, generalmente es el url o el nombre de método que es incorrecto. Incluso que no este configurado el servidor para recibir el tipo de petición PUT.

Comment: Otra opción parecida a lo que comenta Leandro es https://www.hurl.it que yo uso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el fallo era que al final de la URLhabia una / y daba el error 404

Answer (score 0):

Si recibes este mensaje al consultar tu Web Service:

> {"Error en el servidor remoto: (404) No se encontró."}

Puedo sugerirte revisar 3 cosas que generalmente provocan este error:

1. Asegurar tener definida la correcta url del servicio.
2. Asegurar definir el nombre correcto del método a consultar.
3. Agrego otra opción veo que usas el metodo PUT, esta habilitado en el IIS?